# How to automatically hit download URL and download a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In WordPress there's a feature that exports your data into xml files. You can hit this URL with parameters and it will start downloading XML file. The *cat* parameter indicates the ID of the category containing posts you want to include in the XML file.

The problem is that I have over 200 categories and I want to export every category into separate file. So have to hit this url 
http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=posts&cat=" + [category_num] + "&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_status=0

in FOR loop or something like this

```
for (i=1; i <= 200; i++) { 
hit ("http://localhost/lyricsgroove/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=posts&cat="+i+"&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_ status=0");   
}
```

You can try hitting your WP website /wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=posts&cat=1&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_ status=0 and you'll see XML downloading.

I need to do the same but in loop.

I tried doing this in PHP using file_get_contents and in jQuery using $.ajax but none of them starts download.

Comment: Maybe you should try curl in PHP?

Comment: @Michał Thanks! I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=1; i <= 200; i++) { 

     window.open("http://localhost/lyricsgroove/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=posts&cat="+i+"&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_ status=0", "_blank");       
}
```

Warning: This way you try to open 200 new window and browsers will treat them as an unwanted popups. It's not a correct way to export 200 file.

The best way may be to zip all files into one and then download one zipped file.